# what is wrong with my derivative?!!!

Tags: derivatives

I have a question which want to derivative $\left(\frac{3x-2}{5x}\right)$
what I get is $\left(\frac{3\left(5x\right)-5\left(3x-2\right)}{\left(5x\right)^2}\right)$
then $\left(\frac{15x-15x+10}{\left(5x\right)^2}\right)$
and finally 
$\left(\frac{10}{\left(5x\right)^2}\right)$

BUT the correct answer is $\frac{2}{5x^2}$

how it's come?!!

Comment: Don't forget to expand the square $(5x)^2$, then simplify the fraction. You should get the same answer.

Comment: Hey, I was about to type that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not wrong because $$\frac{10}{(5x)^2} = \frac{2}{5x^2} $$

Comment: That's an easy bunch of points.

Comment: @martycohen this answer is dedicated to all the complexe answers which never get upvoted